# Is it possible to create Multiple Setup projects in a single Solution

Tags: .net, desktop-application

Suppose I have 1 solution which contains Project-A, Project-B and Project-C.
In this solution i have Setup-project-1 which use Project-A and Project-B (currently its working fine)

Is it possible to create another Setup-Project-2 in same solution which use Project-B and Project-C for creation of .msi file.

Note: I am new in Desktop development of .net so don't know much about installation of projects.

Comment: I don't recognize the term "Setup-project". Can you describe what you mean by it? But in general - projects form an independent graph, where, typically, start-up projects containing the executable or api server are roots. They depend on other projects, and, usually, nothings depends on them. For example - if you have a project with your DB repositories for data access - you can have two projects that use it in the same solution (for example, Web App and Desktop App). When you build each of them  - they will simply get their own copy of Repo project DLL.

Comment: Actually its a desktop application which needs to be installed on clients machine, so to make the installer we have "installer project"(setup-project) which generate .msi (installer). Hope so it will help to understand. @IvanKoshelev

Comment: From what I understand - there is nothing stopping you from adding additional "installer project" the same way you made the first one and producing alternative MSI with it. In C#, typically, each project produces 1 DLL that is very independent (linked to other projects only by copying the DLL they produces, you can see this in ./bin/debug folder - 1 DLL per referenced project). An MSI, AFAIR, is just a zip of files (EXE and DLLs) and installation scripts. You can have several projects like that in one solution - every one will just output its particular build it its own ./bin

Comment: Keep in mind the setup project is not the modern way to build installers https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-facts-on-visual-studio-setup-projects-45e66fe86d8d